# check if decimal is specified to 2 dp or less

Tags: c#, c#-4.0

I have a string `mystring` that the user enters.  I check that it is a valid decimal thus

```
decimal val;
bool validDecimal = decimal.TryParse(mystring, out val);
if (!validDecimal)
   isvalid = false;
```

But this is not the only validation I need to do.  I also need to check that this decimal is specified to 2 decimal places or less

so,

```
23, 23.1, 23.45
```

are all valid

but

```
23.345, 23.450
```

are not.

What's the best way to do this?

Comment: Good point - even that is not allowed

Comment: Personally I usually allow the user to enter anything that will parse as a decimal, then during validation format and redisplay the value according to the required precision.  So if a user enters "23.451" it will be accepted, but redisplayed as "23.45".

Comment: Joe, that very much depends on the application where it's needed, I guess. There are legitimate reasons for both approaches.

Comment: People suggesting string-parsing answers, it would be nice if your string-parsing matched decimal.Parse, including allowing trailing/leading whitespace and a sign. http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cafs243z.aspx

Answer (score 2, accepted):

How about string parsing.

```
static bool LessThan2DecimalPlaces(string mystring, out decimal val)
{
    bool validDecimal = decimal.TryParse(mystring, out val);
    if (!validDecimal)
    {
       return false;
    }

   var index = mystring.LastIndexOf(NumberFormatInfo.CurrentInfo.NumberDecimalSeparator);
   if(index == -1)
   {
       return true;
   }
   return mystring.Substring(index).Count() < 3
}
```

Comment: The question is "But this is not the only validation I need to do. I also need to check that this decimal is specified to 2 decimal places or less"

Comment: Just so you all know, I did not downvote this.  I'm happy to receive all the help I can.

Comment: @Asif: The point is that I don't understand why someone downvoted you since your solution seems to work.

Comment: @Rawling The last zero is insignificant, there is no difference between 1.230 and 1.23 and 1.2300.

Comment: If you _read the question_ you'll see that it's not insignificant to Sachin.

Comment: @Asif: you should replace `'.'` with `NumberFormatInfo.CurrentInfo.NumberDecimalSeparator.First()` to account for current culture.

Comment: @RăzvanPanda, is there any need of .First()?

Comment: @Asif: If LastIndeOf works only with char as parameter yes. `NumberFormatInfo.CurrentInfo.NumberDecimalSeparator` returns a string, calling `First()` on it returns the first char in the string.

Comment: @Asif: Yeah, I guess it is correct without `First()`. Maybe some languages have multi-character decimal separators.

Answer (score 2):

You could use a regex to validate your original string:

```
Regex.Match(string.Format(@"^\d*({0}\d\d?)?$", CultureInfo.CurrentCulture.NumberFormat.NumberDecimalSeparator), mystring)
```

Answer (score 1):

Since `23.450` isn't allowed, despite the number produced being the same as with `23.45`, you can't test the number itself.

Instead, you have to test the string:

```
decimal val = 0m;
isvalid = isvalid &&
  Regex(@"^\d+(\.\d{1,2})?$").IsMatch(mystring) &&
  decimal.TryParse(mystring, out val);
```

I've taken the approach of initialising `val`, so it doesn't cause issues that `TryParse` is not reached, and only doing the test at all if `isvalid` is currently true, assuming that the operation as a whole will refuse to continue if it's already false for some other reason. Variants are of course possible.

If you're also limiting the number of allowed characters before the `.`, then you could use `Parse` rather than `TryParse`, but I left that as it still handles the case of a number that is too large for the `decimal` datatype.

Edit:

Worth looking at the regex I used in more detail.

`^` matches start of string
`\d+` matches one or more digits
`.` matches a `.`
`\d{1,2}` matches one or two digits
`(\.\d{1,2})?` matches either a `.` followed by one or two digits, or an empty string
`$` matches the end of string

So together, `^\d+(\.\d{1,2})?$` means the entire string must be one or more digits, or one or more digits followed by a `.` followed by one or two digits.

Comment: You _can_ test the number itself - `decimal` knows how many decimal places it was specified with, even if there are trailing zeroes.

Comment: This fails for other cultures.

Comment: @Rawling I've not seen something to suggest clearly that that is more that an implementation artefact, so I'm wary of it. I wish decimal would either make precision an explicit property, or hide it completely.

Comment: @Joey it fails for other conventions. There are times when `.` is expected even in places where `,` is the normal way to write a decimal, and I don't know which this is here. They can use `cultureInQuestion.NumberFormat.NumberDecimalSeparator` with the above if appropriate.

Comment: Good point. The MSDN page for `decimal` is fairly unambiguous - e.g. it says "The scaling factor also preserves any trailing zeroes in a Decimal number. Trailing zeroes do not affect the value of a Decimal number in arithmetic or comparison operations. However, trailing zeroes can be revealed by the ToString method if an appropriate format string is applied." It doesn't, however, mention anything about `decimal.Parse` preserving trailing zeroes, although it currently does.

Comment: @Rawling and even that `ToString()` behaviour is confusing at times. I prefer to avoid it entirely in the absence of a stronger guarantee.

Answer (score 0):

```
var decimalpos = mystring.ToString().Contains(CultureInfo.CurrentCulture.NumberFormat.NumberDecimalSeparator) ? mystring.ToString().IndexOf(CultureInfo.CurrentCulture.NumberFormat.NumberDecimalSeparator) : 0;
   int numberofdecimals 
if decimalpos >0 then    
{
 numberofdecimals = mystring.ToString().Substring(decimalpos,mystring.ToString().Length)
}

if numberofdecimals > 2 then False else True
```

Comment: thanks to @Raphel. using CultureInfo.CurrentCulture.NumberFormat.NumberDecimalSeparator

Answer (score 0):

Check out [Decimal.GetBits](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.decimal.getbits.aspx).

> The fourth element of the returned array contains the scale factor and sign. It consists of the following parts:
>
> ...
>
> Bits 16 to 23 must contain an exponent between 0 and 28, which indicates the power of 10 to divide the integer number.

This works.

```
public int PlacesSpecified(decimal d)
{
    var lastInt = decimal.GetBits(d)[3];
    return (lastInt >> 16) & 255
}
```